# CQRS + ES: Splitting monolith to microservices database issue

Tags: subquery, microservices, cqrs

When we use the relational database to do multi-table subquery, e.g.

`` select * from `t_a` a where exist (select pid from` t_b` b where b.pid = a.pid group by pid) ``

if table t_a, t_b are in the same database, then it is easy to achieve the subquery, if we split these two tables (more than millions of rows) into two microservices A and B, service A has database db_a, it has table t_a, service B has database db_b, it has table t_b.

My question is: how does CQRS & ES implement data aggregation?

I'm struggling this issue for a long time, searched so many articles, but I didn't find any useful answer, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Long story short: you denormalize the data, you copy data from one ms to another using the events, in this way you won't need any joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CQRS+Event sourcing you won't necessarily need any joins. Why? See below.

On the write side you have the aggregates that are rehydrated from the event store by replaying the previous events so no joins.

On the read side you have the readmodels/projection and sagas. Here, you denormalize the data. You design your models to contain all the data that is needed by the clients. For example, on the list of comments of a post in a blog you put the author's username also, along with its ID. In this way you don't need to fetch data from the users table because the data is already there (you won't need a general purpose users table either).

There is the question of data freshness. You keep the related/denormalized data fresh by listening to the relevant events. For our example, your readmodel listens to the `UsernameWasChanged` event and change the username for all its posts.

CQRS makes the joins obsolete.

Comment: PS. I'm currently working on a big CRM web application with many many (100+) models and I have no joins.